# Solution needed for mouse over event requirement

Tags: css, mouseover

I have a mouse over requirement that I cannot make happen, and ask if someone can help me find the solution.

In [this page](http://opticeye.co.uk/wilsons/sales.html) there are images, below which is a section which turns blue on mouse over, however I hope to make the same section turn blue when the whole section, including the image, has a mouse over event.

Please share any thoughts on how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define these hovers instead of the ones you got:

```
.thumb-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 9px 13px 26px -8px #222533;
}

.thumb-shadow:hover .capt_hover1 {
  background: rgba(33, 194, 248, 0.8);
}

.thumb-shadow:hover .capt_hover1 * {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.thumb-shadow:hover .capt_hover1 .btn-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius and you have my deepest gratitude. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a simple way to make this same thing happen when the image is displayed on a mobile device?

Comment: When do you want it to change appearance? When the user presses and holds on the section?

Comment: I hoped to have it change appearance when the section is viewed on the screen, or scrolled past, without the need to press and hold, which is what already happens now. I was told this is possible, but can't find a solution.